# What is the difference between (Id)str and Id.valueOf(str)?

Tags: apex, bestpractice, performance, data-types, typecast

Say I have one string `String strId = 001xa000003DIlo` and I want to typecast it to an Id. So I have two options to do so:

1. `Id idVal = (Id)strId;`
2. `Id idVal = Id.valueOf(strId);`

Which is the best way to achieve this purpose?

What exactly is the difference between these two approaches?

Is the difference same for typecasting a `String`, `Decimal` or any other datatype?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The first is casting. The second is calling a static method on the `Id` class.

One major advantage of the *former* is that it is more null safe.

```
Id idVal1 = (Id)null; // works
Id idVal2 = Id.valueOf(null); // blows up
```

One advantage of the *latter* is that you can one-line more of your code by calling instance methods on the cast result. You *can* get one-liners by adding some parentheses to the casting approach, though some might object on stylistic grounds. I find it a little more visually confusing.

```
SObjectType t1a = (Id)'001000000000000AAA'.getSObjectType(); // blows up
SObjectType t1b = ((Id)'001000000000000AAA').getSObjectType(); // works
SObjectType t2 = Id.valueOf('001000000000000AAA').getSObjectType(); // works
```

The above pros/cons are independent of type, so you can carry these conclusions over to `String`, `Decimal`, etc.

Comment: Just FYI you can still one line while casting like this `((Id)idPropertyVal).getSObjectType();`  - You cannot do `(Id)'001000000000000AAA'` anyway as it throws an error....

Answer (score 13):

Casting is not required to convert a `String` to an `Id`:

```
String strVal = '001000000000000AAA';
Id idVal1 = strVal;
Id idVal2 = '001000000000000AAA';
```

`Id` is a specialization of `String`.

This can be shown by:

```
Id idVal = '001000000000000AAA';
System.assert(idVal instanceof String); // ERROR: Operation instanceof is always true since an instance of Id is always an instance of String
```

There is a slight difference in heap space used for `Id.valueOf` vs cast:

```
Id id1 = '001000000000000';
Id id2 = (Id) id1;
System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize()); // 1047
```

vs

```
Id id1 = '001000000000000';
Id id2 = Id.valueOf(id1);
System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize()); // 1051
```

Comment: I am aware of that @Alan, However I wanted to know the difference between these two approaches and their proper usages which Adrian has described. Thanks anyways. Cheers !!!

Comment: Sometimes it's required. For instance, you may want to use `Id` instance methods.

Comment: Probably should do many runs to analyze heap usage. It tends to vary slightly each execution.

Comment: @AdrianLarson No, heap size is always consistent between runs of the exact same code in the exact same environment. The four byte difference means that a new object is being allocated on the heap. I also personally know that casting is faster than Id.valueOf by a small margin, so casting actually uses less memory, less CPU time, and less code characters. It is therefore essentially a useless function to have exposed at the user level.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Just did some testing... casting is about 3x times faster than Id.valueOf. The More You Know.

Comment: @sfdcfox I'm sure we'd welcome another answer if you're willing to share. :) I think I got similar numbers last time I looked.

Comment: @sfdcfox, yes, It would be great for our knowledge if you could share your answer.

Comment: Despite what SF says (Operation instanceof is always true since an instance of Id is always an instance of String) it's not quite true.
Using your example, idVal.length() doesn't return 18 but 'Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void length() from the type Id'.
If Id really inherited from String, this should work